# Laravel Model Relationship on Non-Static Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

So, I have a legacy Database, with a poorly designed structure that has recently been moved to Laravel, but with some hacky nonsense to get it to work with models. Given the following Tables:

```
|==========================|====|============|===========|
| companies                | id | token      | name      |
|--------------------------|----|------------|-----------|
| people_{companies.token} | id | first_name | last_name |
|==========================|====|============|===========|
```

The `companies` table contains multiple records, with an auto-incrementing ID, unique `token`, and `name`.

Each Company has its own `people_{companies.token}` table, instead of a single `people` table, with an associated `client_id`.

At first, this meant I couldn't use a standard `Company` and `Person` Model/Relationships, as `protected $table` needs to be static. We got around this with a `DynamicBinding` Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

trait DynamicBinding {
  protected $connection = null;
  protected $table = null;

  public function bind(string $connection, string $table) {
    $this->setConnection($connection);
    $this->setTable($table);
  }

  public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false) {
    $model = parent::newInstance($attributes, $exists);
    $model->setTable($this->table);

    return $model;
  }
}
```

This allows for setting a table on the fly:

```
$company = Company::first();
$people = (new Person())->setTable("people_{$company->token}");
$person = $people->first();
```

This works perfectly fine, returning the first record from the `people_{$company->token}` table, and facilitating most functionality required. Now, I'd like to make this work with Relationships. Given the following example:

```
// Person.php
public function company() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}

$company = Company::first();
$people = (new Person())->setTable("people_{$company->token}");

$person = $people->first(); // No Issue
$peopleWithCompany = $people->with('company')->first(); // Cannot find table `people`
```

This returns the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.people' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `people` limit 1)

Essentially, as soon as `->with()` (or other functions, like `->query()`, etc) is appended, it tries to perform the query based on the determined table (`people` from `Person`) instead of the table set via `$people->setTable()`.

Does anyone have any experience connecting models to this kind of data structure, while allowing use of Eager Loading with Relationships? And sidenote, there is a plan to migrate everything to a single `people` table, but unfortunately not anytime soon...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're still having this problem, my first idea is to create a SQL view defined as the union of all people_{token} tables and treat that view as the People model's table.

Comment: Second idea is to pass the token to the relationship method somehow. This however, would only work for the case of a single Company querying it's people. Instead of `$people->with('company')->first()` you'd be forced to do something like `$company = Company::whereHas('people')->first(); $company->setToken($company->token)->load(['people' => fn($p) => $p->limit(1)]);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions IGP. Thankfully this statement: *"And sidenote, there is a plan to migrate everything to a single people table, **but unfortunately not anytime soon...**"* turned out to be false, and the Migration has taken place to normalized tables.

Comment: Glad to hear it